# Python - merge dataframes to replace missing values with the actual ones

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have a list of 20 dataframes with sports results with this structure:

| Key1 | Key2 | Variable1 | Variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TeamA | TeamB | 20 | Nan |
| TeamC | TeamA | Nan | 25 |
| TeamA | TeamD | 17 | Nan |

| Key1 | Key2 | Variable1 | Variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TeamA | TeamB | Nan | 45 |
| TeamB | TeamC | 90 | Nan |
| TeamB | TeamD | 57 | Nan |

| Key1 | Key2 | Variable1 | Variable2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TeamC | TeamA | 18 | Nan |
| TeamB | TeamC | Nan | 17 |
| TeamC | TeamD | 84 | Nan |

I guess you get the idea: each dataframe has all the games for a particular team and several variables realted to that team, while the variables for the other team are empty. I would like to merge all the dataframes in a single one, so the Nan are replaced by the correct value. I have been trying to use pandas merge, but I could not get it right. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) ... Your question is too broad. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Please always provide a [mre]. - emphasis on minimal, often making a minimal toy example that illustrates your problem will help you solve it.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are those actual `Nan`'s or strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try it like this... This is just for creating your datafiles (I saved them as .csv and then read them in). Keep in mind that I read in your 'Nan'-values so that pandas recognizes them:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r'C:\...'
df1_fl = r'2020-12-31_df1.csv'
df2_fl = r'2020-12-31_df2.csv'
df3_fl = r'2020-12-31_df3.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, df1_fl), sep=';', na_values='Nan')
df2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, df2_fl), sep=';', na_values='Nan')
df3 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, df3_fl), sep=';', na_values='Nan')
```

Then I just replace the nan-values with a zero value and aggregate all your data together in one dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).fillna(0)
```

Then the interesting part starts, grouping the data by the columns 'Key1' and 'Key2', finding the max over the group (this fills up the nan values). In the end, you need to extract out the now existing multi-index in two columns as given in the beginning dataframes with reset_index.

```
df_agg = df.groupby(by=['Key1', 'Key2']).max().reset_index()
```

Comment: For the given data this is a nice solution. I was wondering if `max` aggregation would be more general, if values for the same group were present in more than one file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked great! There was a little caveat, as there were some values that were real missing values and I did not want to lose that information. I saw that keeping them as nan and using "min_count=1" in sum gave me the result I was looking for.

Comment: Hey Michael, I like your advice, could be useful in some case. Hey Manu, like to hear